# Get text between tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get prices from between span tags. I would like to have all prices in an array. I cant seem to get it to work, I am guessing my regex is incorrect.

I am looking for any span tags with the class 'amount', the tag has no other attributes set and only has one class. E.g. `<span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span>`

```
var prices = resp.fragments['data'].match(/<span class=\"amount\">(.*?)<\/span>/g)
    .map(function(val){
      return val;
});
```

Output

`[ '&pound;9.99', '&pound;100.00' ]`

I am trying to get prices from between span tags. I would like to have all prices in an array. I cant seem to get it to work, I am guessing my regex is incorrect.

I am looking for any span tags with the class 'amount', the tag has no other attributes set and only has one class. E.g. `<span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span>`

```
var prices = resp.fragments['data'].match(/<span class=\"amount\">(.*?)<\/span>/g)
    .map(function(val){
      return val;
});
```

Output

`[ '&pound;9.99', '&pound;100.00' ]`

*** UPDATE ***

Turns out it was an encoding with the ajax response `resp.fragments['data']`.

I was using regex as it is something I have not really used before in JS and thought I would have a play. I did look at many examples and after about 45 mins with no success I thought a fresh set of eyes would fix it.

Comment: From the example you've given, it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: `$('span.amount').val()`, won't work?

Comment: [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Is there any reason that you want to use a regular expression for this? It may be easier to simply target your `<span class='amount'>` elements and grab the text from each of them.

Comment: you can also use jQuery to select element+class `$("span.amount")` if jQuery is an option

Comment: You can use jquery to get the results via DOM parsing: `$('span').each(function(index, value) { console.log($(value).text()); })`

Comment: sweet lord, there are a lot of jQuery suggestions for a question tagged JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a regular expression could work for this, it might be easier to simply select the `<span class='amount'>` elements and map their [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) content to an array via the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
// This would yield an array containing your values
var amounts = Array.prototype.slice
                             .call(document.querySelectorAll('span.amount'))
                             .map(function(a){ return a.innerHTML; });
```

You can [see a working example of this demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/duqobi/edit?html,console,output).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method will be to add this to an invisible DOM object and then traverse it via DOM API

```
var text  = '<span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span><span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span>'
```

//now append it to an DOM object

```
var wrapperDiv = "<div style='display:none' id='tmpDiv'>" + text + "</div>";
document.body.innerHTML += wrapperDiv;

var elements = document.querySelectorAll( "#tmpDiv amount" );
var output = Array.prototype.slice.call( elements ).map( function(val){
  return val.innerText;
})
```

**Another approach** could be `split` the text by `<span class="amount">` and get the value after first index

**DEMO**

```js
    var text  = '<span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span><span class="amount">&pound;9.99</span>'
    var output = [];
text.split('<span class="amount">').forEach( function(val, index) {
   if (index > 0 )
   {
      output.push( val.replace( "</span>", "" ) );
   }
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( output, 0, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead.

```js
var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
var price_array = [];

for (i= 0; i < prices.length; ++i) {
    price_array.push(prices[i].innerHTML);
}

document.write(" | " + price_array);
```

```html
<span class='amount'>&pound;123</span>
<span class='amount'>&pound;3</span>
<span class='amount'>&pound;5</span>
<span class='amount'>&pound;64</span>
```

You don't need to use regex or jQuery for this.